# How can i increase or decrease the volume gradually using sound fading option?

Tags: android

i am new to android .
I have a small problem in my application.i am doing a alarm application ,in that application one option like this "sound fade in".
What is the meaning of "sound fade in". I think the ringing volume of alarm tone is gradually increasing for the given period of time. Am i correct?
then i can i achieve this sound fade in..
please help me if you can....

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need in the the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) class. You can look at the source code of the Music application to get a sample of how to fade out the sound. I can't give you a link right now as the [Android Git](http://android.git.kernel.org/) is not working for now :(.